# Equivalent tool as MAC agent in Visual Studio 2017 for Nativescript using Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript, sidekick

I am new to Nativescript.

Need to know if there is any tool available to connect to MAC emulator like we have MAC agent in Visual Studio 2017 for Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have anything as such with Sidekick,  yet. Only could builds are supported at the moment which requires real device.